# str_pad don't works in Mysql field using Yii2

Tags: controller, yii2, action

I have this create action in Yii2 controller:

```
public function actionCreate2()
    {
      $searchModel = new BibliografieSearch();
      $searchModel = new CodiciSearch();
      $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);    

        $model = new Elenchi();  
        $model->Modified = date( 'y-m-d' );
        
        
        if ($model->FogliDaO) {
            $model->FogliDaO = str_pad($model->FogliDaO, 8, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
        }

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            
            return $this->redirect(['index', 'sort' => '-IDElenco']);
        }

        return $this->render('create2', [
            'model' => $model,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'searchModel' => $searchModel


        ]);
    }
```

Now, if I write "28v" in field (FogliDaO) and I save the new record the result in Mysql database is always "28v", instead of "0000028v". Where I'm wrong? (FogliDaO is VARCHAR). I need help.
Thank you very much!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want change the content of the $model you mustassign the padded value  after the load() and before the save() function  .. otherwise you overwrite the assigment

```
public function actionCreate2()
{
  $searchModel = new BibliografieSearch();
  $searchModel = new CodiciSearch();
  $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);    

    $model = new Elenchi();  
    
    

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) ) {
        $model->Modified = date( 'y-m-d' );
        
        if ($model->FogliDaO) {
            $model->FogliDaO = str_pad($model->FogliDaO, 8, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
        }
        $model->save();
        return $this->redirect(['index', 'sort' => '-IDElenco']);
    }

    return $this->render('create2', [
        'model' => $model,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'searchModel' => $searchModel


    ]);
}
```

the $model->load() function copy the correspondent model data from $_POST to your actual (new) model  ..  so if you assign the padded  value before the load() function this value is lost because the load overwrite this value with the $_POST content

Comment: Great! Can I ask you here another help about the same question?

Comment: @marcodemurtas  .. sure ..  if  is a new question  you could post a new question weel documented  and comment me the link  ..  otherwise if is only a clarification  about the orginal question 
 .. you can comment me  the issue

Comment: ok I post a new question in a few minutes. Thank you!